# Github Pages can't find React site

Tags: html, reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm trying to launch a photography site on Github Pages, but when I tried to deploy, the link says "Site not found", despite the rest of the index.html appearing

It shows the title and "hello world", but does not show the actual site. The site used to work locally, but it only shows the "hello world, site not found" now.

Site: https://ohong87.github.io/portfolio/

Repo: https://github.com/ohong87/portfolio

Edit**Caught the error - "Page does not exist" is the default message for when the current URL does not match any of the routing. Now trying to figure out why the main page is not showing by default

Answer (score 0):

Please change your repo name to "ohong87.github.io"
And in your repo, you must use build file.
current project is react project.
so you must build react project to html file.
Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).